# Does Zuul have any support issues in SpringBoot 2.7 and Java 11?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-11, netflix-zuul

I am trying to implement Zuul in my SpringBoot Gradle project. I am facing some issues while running the application and I have tried almost all the ways that I could find online. Does anyone know what went wrong here ?.

This is my Gradle Build file

```
    plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
    }
    
    group = 'com.zuul'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '11'
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:2.2.10.RELEASE'
// implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-zuul', version: '1.4.7.RELEASE'
        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    
    }
    
    tasks.named('test') {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }
```

the error that I'm getting while starting the application

```
 2022-07-12 18:27:11.008  WARN 22976 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a]
    2022-07-12 18:27:11.032  INFO 22976 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
    
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2022-07-12 18:27:11.065 ERROR 22976 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at com.zuul.DemoZuulApplication.main(DemoZuulApplication.java:15) ~[main/:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
    
    2022-07-12 18:27:11.072 ERROR 22976 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
    
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesBeans' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:164) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
        at com.zuul.DemoZuulApplication.main(DemoZuulApplication.java:15) ~[main/:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a]
    
        ... 30 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
        ... 37 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
    
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2cdf8d8a]
    
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    
    
    > Task :DemoZuulApplication.main() FAILED
    
    Execution failed for task ':DemoZuulApplication.main()'.
    > Process 'command 'C:/temp/java11/jdk-11.0.15/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Spring Cloud Zuul is build using Spring Boot 2.3 and as such won't work with Spring Boot 2.7 due to moved classes etc. The last version of Spring Cloud to use/support Zuul was Spring Cloud Hoxton, the Netflix stuff was, mostly, removed in the next 2021 release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring Cloud Zuul was last part of the Spring Cloud Hoxton release, which was compatible with Spring Boot 2.2 and 2.3 Later releases removed most of the support for the Netflix libraries (as announced [here](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/23/spring-cloud-roadmap-and-hoxton-and-greenwich-maintenance-and-eol-announcements), more info [here](https://spring.io/blog/2018/12/12/spring-cloud-greenwich-rc1-available-now#spring-cloud-netflix-projects-entering-maintenance-mode)), as mentioned in [the release notes](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes-1).

So no Spring Cloud Zuul will not work with Spring Boot 2.7 as Spring Cloud versions are strictly tied to certain Spring Boot versions.

Instead you should use the new gateway support in Spring Cloud instead of Zuul.

Comment: Is this new gateway support the Spring Cloud Gateway? In the docs, https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway, they say that it is for API Gateway on top of Spring Webflux. Is right the understanding that my app based on servlets won't work with this new Spring Cloud solution?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Gateway is just a proxy routing to your app, how that app is build doesn't matter.